# Avoid filter on asynchronous ng-options default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-filters

An update to angularjs 1.3.6 broke some of my filters.

I tried to fix them and get to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/takuan/ev4zvu2z/) solution.

Hide the default option:

```
<select ng-model="search.type" ng-options="g.id as g.name for g in group">
    <option ng-show="false" value="">Any</option>
</select>
```

Add an 'Any' option that won't filter the list.

```
$scope.group = [];
$scope.group[0] = {id:'',name:'Any'};
```

Does anyone have a better solution to do this ? Using this ng-show trick don't seems that good to me.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. What did the last alternative (was this the one you wanted?) solve?

Comment: @NewDev the last alternative solve the issue, but it seems ugly to me. I hope someone have a cleaner solution.

Comment: I'm not understanding the issue.

Comment: @NewDev even if my solution is "working" I'm looking for a better way to do it. Using ng-show="false" on the first option is more like a workaround than a proper solution.

Comment: I meant that I don't fully understand the issue. Not that "there is no issue since you solved it". Is it the disappearing blank option?

Comment: @NewDev the disapearing blank option is something I try to avoid yes, I also don't want the default option to filter the ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did almost everything correctly. There are 2 things missing and then you don't need the `ng-show` hack:

1. make the ViewModel property of the `<select>` to be the actual filtering object, rather than just the `Id` property, and change the filter string appropriately.
2. Make the ViewModel property equal to the "Any" object - this will set the `<select>` to the correct option.

1)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:search.type">
    {{item.name}}
</div>

<select ng-model="search" ng-options="g as g.name for g in group">
</select>
```

2)

```
$scope.search = $scope.group[0] = {id:'',name:'Any'};
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1o1az2Lw/)

Comment: Is there a way to keep only `filter:search` in the ng-repeat ? having `ng-model="search.type"` in the select is usefull if I have several dropdown list to filter different fields.

Comment: Again, I don't know exactly what you mean. If you have additional requirements, then please ask another question where you would have the opportunity to explain what you have and what you want the result to be.